# How to reset mySql root password

Tags: mysql

I tried resetting mySql password using official documentation but its not working,

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.7/en/resetting-permissions-windows.html

its giving me error

```
[![C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0>mysqld --init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt --console
2021-12-16T18:33:22.801467Z 0 \[System\] \[MY-010116\] \[Server\] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.26) starting as process 14656
2021-12-16T18:33:22.803505Z 0 \[Warning\] \[MY-010091\] \[Server\] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2021-12-16T18:33:22.803577Z 0 \[Warning\] \[MY-010091\] \[Server\] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2021-12-16T18:33:22.803754Z 0 \[ERROR\] \[MY-013276\] \[Server\] Failed to set datadir to 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\' (OS errno: 2 - No such file or directory)
2021-12-16T18:33:22.804645Z 0 \[ERROR\] \[MY-010119\] \[Server\] Aborting
2021-12-16T18:33:22.804771Z 0 \[System\] \[MY-010910\] \[Server\] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.26)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.][1]][1]
```

Comment: Sounds like you are running the install without using the admin account

Comment: There are numerous duplicates of this question at [dba.se]

Comment: Use "Generic Instructions" procedure from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: *its giving me error* Have you logged as Administrator? Does this Administrator Windows account have permissions for to create files in the `@@datadir` forder? Have you started the console where you tries to start `mysqld.exe` using "Run as Administrator" in the context menu of cmd.exe?

Answer (score 0):

For windows 10

1. Delete **Data** folder present inside `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0`
2. Create file named `mysql-init.txt` and copy paste below lines and
   store at C:\

   `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'root';`
3. Open **CMD** as admin cd to path `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin>`
   and enter following commands one by one

`mysqld -install`

`mysqld --initialize`

`mysqld --init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt --console`

Comment: *Delete `Data` folder present inside `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0`* - there is no such folder if default install settings were used during MySQL installation.